# How to create a row of 2 items retrieved from mysql database in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, for-loop, foreach

So I'm working on my portfolio page. I have all of my projects entered into a mysql database. I can get the data back and put them to render into individual rows on my webpage but I want to have two projects rendered in each row (ie two mysql row data rendered in each new row) of the webpage.

I haven't been able to figure out how to accomplish this.

Here is my blade

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')

{{-- Search --}}
{{-- <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
                <form action=" {{ route('projects.postSearch') }} " method="get" class="form-inline">
                        <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="search" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="search contacts">
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group-prepend" style="margin-top:20px;">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
                        </div>
                </form>
        </div>
</div> --}}

{{-- All Projects --}}

<div class="containter">
    <div style="align-content: center; margin-left: 10%">
    @foreach ($projects as $key => $value)
        <div class="row" style="align-content:center">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                <div class="row" style="align-items-center">
                    <h3 class="col">{{$value->projectName}}</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="row" style="align-items-center">
                    <div class="col"><a href="{{$value->url}}"><img src="assets/img/{{$value->img}}" style="width: 200%"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                        <p class="col">{{$value->description}}</p>
                        <p class="col">{{$value->keywords}}</p>
                        <a href="{{$value->github}}"><img src="{{asset('/assets/img/githublogo.gif')}}" style="width: 50%">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
    {{-- {{ $projects->links() }} --}}
</div>

@endsection
```

Here is my controller code for this blade

```
    public function index()
    {
        $projects = Projects::orderBy('ranking')->paginate(10);
        return view('projects.index', ['projects' => $projects]);
    }
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: you want to add a new `<div class="row" style="align-content:center">` every 2 entries, correct?

Comment: I assume you're using bootstrap? If so, what version of bootstrap are you using? Also, can you explain how the list is currently being rendered and what the issue is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `chunk` your collection by 2 elements to get what you are trying to achieve:

```
@foreach($projects->chunk(2) as $chunk)
    <div class="row" style="align-content:center">
        @foreach ($chunk as $key => $value)
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                <div class="row" style="align-items-center">
                    <h3 class="col">{{$value->projectName}}</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="row" style="align-items-center">
                    <div class="col"><a href="{{$value->url}}"><img src="assets/img/{{$value->img}}"
                                                                    style="width: 200%"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <p class="col">{{$value->description}}</p>
                    <p class="col">{{$value->keywords}}</p>
                    <a href="{{$value->github}}"><img src="{{asset('/assets/img/githublogo.gif')}}"
                                                      style="width: 50%"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks That worked perfectly!!! I am going to be using chunk all the time now lol. That's a great piece of info I didn't know. Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 0):

Cols have to exist inside a row:

```
<div class="row>
    <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
        <form action=" {{ route('projects.postSearch') }} " method="get" class="form-inline">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="search" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="search contacts">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group-prepend" style="margin-top:20px;">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```